# How to execute a script in SharePoint Management Shell?

Tags: powershell

> PS C:\logfiles> dir
>
> ```
> Directory: C:\logfiles
> ```
>
> Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
>   ----                -------------     ------ ----
>   -a---        12/11/2013   2:54 PM      50707 Detail_LandingPage.txt
>   -a---        12/12/2013  10:36 AM       1641 Post-KJUninstall.ps1
>
> PS C:\logfiles> Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath
>   C:\LogFiles\Detail_La ndingPage.txt }" Unexpected token '}' in
>   expression or statement. At line:1 char:80
>   + Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPage.txt  } <<<< "
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (}:String) [], ParentContainsErrorR    ecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
>
> PS C:\logfiles> Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath
>   C:\LogFiles\Detail_La ndingPage.txt"
>
> > > Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPage.txt "
> > >       The term 'Post-KJUninstall.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, func tion, script file, or operable program. Check the
> > >       spelling of the name, or if a  path was included, verify that the path
> > >       is correct and try again. At line:1 char:21
> > >       + Post-KJUninstall.ps1 <<<<  -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPa ge.txt"
> > >           + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Post-KJUninstall.ps1:String) []    , CommandNotFoundException
> > >           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> PS C:\logfiles> PS C:\logfiles> Post-KJUninstall.ps1
>   -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_La ndingPage.txt"
>
> > >
> >     >
> >     >
> >     >
> >
> > > Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPage.txt "
> > >       The term 'Post-KJUninstall.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, func tion, script file, or operable program. Check the
> > >       spelling of the name, or if a  path was included, verify that the path
> > >       is correct and try again. At line:1 char:21
> > >       + Post-KJUninstall.ps1 <<<<  -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPa ge.txt"
> > >           + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Post-KJUninstall.ps1:String) []    , CommandNotFoundException
> > >           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> PS C:\logfiles> Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath
>   C:\LogFiles\Detail_La ndingPage.txt The term 'Post-KJUninstall.ps1' is
>   not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, func tion, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a  path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1
>   char:21
>   + Post-KJUninstall.ps1 <<<<  -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPa ge.txt
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Post-KJUninstall.ps1:String) []    , CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> PS C:\logfiles> c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath
>   C:\LogFil es\Detail_LandingPage.txt The term
>   'c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the n ame, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again. At line:1 char:33
>   + c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 <<<<  -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Deta il_LandingPage.txt
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps    1:String) [],
>   CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> PS C:\logfiles> c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath
>   C:\LogFil es\Detail_LandingPage.txt

```
Param($UninstallLogFilePath) 
$file = $UninstallLogFilePath 

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 

$powerPivotFeatures = @("1a33a234-b4a4-4fc6-96c2-8bdb56388bd5", "e9c4784b-d453-46f5-8559-3c891d7159dd", "f8c51e81-0b46-4535-a3d5-244f63e1cab9") 
$premiumSiteId = "8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2" 

#Remove PowerPivot features 
foreach($featureId in $powerPivotFeatures) 
{ 
    if(Get-SPFeature | where {$_.Id -eq $featureId}) 
    { 
        Write-Host "Found feature $featureId" 
        Uninstall-SPFeature -Id $featureId -force 
    } 
} 

# Verify if the premium site feature was indeed removed 
$premiumSiteFeature = Get-SPFeature | where {$_.Id -eq $premiumSiteId} 
if($premiumSiteFeature -eq $null) 
{ 
    # Re-install the feature 
    Install-SPFeature -path PremiumSite 
} 

switch -regex -file $file 
{ 
    "de-activating feature"    { 
                    # This will return every entry in the file for feature deactivation 
                    $Url = $_.Split() | ?{$_ -match "http://([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)([\.][[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*(\:[0-9]+)*(/\S*)?"} 
                    #Remove the period at the end 
                    $Url = $Url.Substring(0, $Url.Length – 1) 
                    # Match the Guid for the feature 
                    $Id = $_.Split() | ?{$_ -match "([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}"} 
                    if(!($powerPivotFeatures -contains $Id)) 
                    { 
                        Write-Host "Re-activating feature $Id on site $Url" 
                        Enable-SPFeature -Id $Id -Url $Url 
                        trap 
                            { 
                                Write-Host "Could not Re-activate feature $Id on site $Url" 
                                Write-Host $("Exception: "+ $_.Exception.Message); 
                                continue 
                            } 
                    } 

                    continue 
                } 
}
```

Comment: If you changed the title to PowerShell instead of SharePoint Management Shell, this question would be out of topic for SharePoint StackExchange. Is this working in PS but not in SharePoint Management Shell, or is there any other reason why this question belongs here?

Answer (score 4):

to execute a script in powershell, create the script in notepad++ save as .ps1 (powershell).

save to desktop.

open powershell as admin, drag the file from desktop and drop the file into the shell and hit enter. It should run fine!

**edit**

Please make sure you follow these steps!

1) run  sharepoint 2010 managment shell as admin

2) run this code:  `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell`

3) create your ps1 from notepad++ as it contains the extention method .ps1 when you save the file rather than renaming the file from a text file!

4) save the file to desktop

5) drag the saved file and drop it into sharepoint 2010 managment shell, now hit enter... it should run your code within your file!

just try the above to see it work! dont do: `Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_La ndingPage.txt` all you want to see is if its going to run your ps1 file first!

**EDIT**

now we know its not your powershell thats broken but the script!

look at your params:

```
Param($UninstallLogFilePath)
```

change to

```
Param([String]$UninstallLogFilePath="")
```

now in powershell do:

```
Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath "C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPage.txt"
```

Comment: I get that error:

PS C:\logfiles> c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFil es\Detail_LandingPage.txt The term 'c:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using? 2010?

Comment: yes 2010 Ali!!!

Comment: are you opening sharepoint 2010 managment shell? or are you using the standard powershell?

Comment: sharepoint 2010 managment shell

Comment: goto start -> all programmes -> microsoft sharepoint 2010 products -> right click sharepoint 2010 managment shell and click on run as admin! then do the ps scrip as noted above!

Comment: PS C:\Users\administrator.ENCARA> C:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UninstallLog
FilePath C:\LogFiles\Detail_LandingPage.txt
The term 'C:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the n
ame, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:33
+ C:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 <<<<  -UninstallLogFilePath C:\LogFiles\Deta
il_LandingPage.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps
   1:Stri ...

Comment: how did you make the powershell script?

Comment: I will past it in a new answer Ali

Comment: it looks like your powershell is missing the correct dll, this is why im asking you these questions! try reloading the dll, do this is powershell    "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"  without the quotes ;)

Comment: its alread added !! :(

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: It works but without the paramns I need!

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: lets try it ....

Comment: Ali, thank you so much for your help,
But now Im getting that: PS C:\logfiles> C:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1 -UnistallLogFilePath "C:\LogFil
es\Detail_LandingPage.txt"
Invalid filename argument to -file in switch statement.
At C:\LogFiles\Post-KJUninstall.ps1:26 char:26
+ switch -regex -file $file <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidFilenameOption

PS C:\logfiles>

Comment: Im trying to figure out this solution:
http://powerpivotgeek.com/2010/06/14/uninstalling-powerpivot-does-what-arg/

Comment: ok so its now working! its now calling the ps1 file and executing the command, its failing within the script at line 26, so i could be the param this is wrong! if you could change [String] to [string] , i think string should be in lower case not upper! http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx

Comment: No sucess ! :P !!!!